# Get ArgumentError ets.lookup in Absinthe Middleware using FunWithFlags

Tags: elixir, middleware, absinthe

I’m trying to use `FunWithFlags.enabled?` (ref [fwf](https://github.com/tompave/fun_with_flags)) inside an absinthe [middleware/3](https://hexdocs.pm/absinthe/Absinthe.Schema.html#c:middleware/3) callback but I got the following error:

```
(ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:fun_with_flags_cache, :some_flag)

Stacktrace:
  │ lib/fun_with_flags/store/cache.ex:35: FunWithFlags.Store.Cache.get/1
  │ lib/fun_with_flags/store.ex:12: FunWithFlags.Store.lookup/1
  │ lib/fun_with_flags.ex:77: FunWithFlags.enabled?/2
```

I haven’t tried too much. I just narrowed down where the issue is happening. I’m guessing the middleware compiles before the `:some_flag record` (or maybe the `:fun_with_flags_cache` table) is created and then failed because there is no record/table.

[This](https://www.flagship.io/github-feature-flags/) link says:

> It stores flag information in Redis or a relational DB (PostgreSQL or MySQL, with Ecto) for persistence and synchronization across different nodes, but it also maintains a local cache in an ETS table for fast lookups. When flags are added or toggled on a node, the other nodes are notified via PubSub and reload their local ETS caches.

I already tried to disable the ETS with the following config:

```
config :fun_with_flags, :cache,
  enabled: false,
```

But I didn't work. :(

Here is an example of how I'm using it:

```
defmodule MyApp.Schema do
use Absinthe.Schema
...
  def middleware(middleware, field, object) do
  FunWithFlags.enabled?(:some_flag) # <-- (ArgumentError) argument error (stdlib) :ets.lookup...
  ...
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure `:fun_with_flags` application gets started **before** you reference it. Without seeing more code it’s impossible to narrow the issue down better.

Comment: Hi @AlekseiMatiushkin, thanks for your replying. I added an example of how I'm using it. What you said makes sense. Do you have any idea of how I can do that? The only places where I see FunWithFlags is on `mix.exs` and `config.exs`. The first one is to add the dependency and the second to set some configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the documentation explicitly mentions possible race conditions, I’d suggest you start the FwF application manually as described in [Application Start Behaviour](https://github.com/tompave/fun_with_flags#application-start-behaviour) section of the documentation.

In `mix.exs`:

```
- {:fun_with_flags, "~> 1.6"},
+ {:fun_with_flags, "~> 1.6", runtime: false},
```

and in your `Application.start/1` callback:

```
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      ...,
+     FunWithFlags.Supervisor,
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

Comment: It sounds promising but I tried both options (A and B) proposed on the repo but no luck yet. I also, delete the `deps` and the `_build` directories. I used `mix clean`. If you have an app using Absinthe could you confirm that after doing that works or not? Thanks in advance. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!